# How can I retrieve a lost login token for KubeApps?

Tags: secret-management, authentication, kubeapps

How can I retrieve the root token from a KubeApps deployment?

Comment: What details or clarity is needed here, it's a self answered question?

Comment: Note this is self-answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up a KubeApps deployment you must install a Kubernetes secret, [currently the installation instructions](https://kubeapps.dev/) detail it like this,

```yaml
kubectl create clusterrolebinding kubeapps-operator --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:kubeapps-operator

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: kubeapps-operator-token
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: kubeapps-operator
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
EOF

kubectl get --namespace default secret kubeapps-operator-token -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' -o go-template='{{.data.token | base64decode}}' && echo
```

So basically it's a [service-account-token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) installed in the default namespace. You can list these like this,

```
 kubectl get --namespace default secrets
```

You specifically want the `kubeapps-operator-token` and you can get it with the last line,

```
kubectl get --namespace default secret kubeapps-operator-token -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' -o go-template='{{.data.token | base64decode}}'
```

The  `-o go-template='{{.data.token | base64decode}}'` is basically just piping it to `base64 -d` in Go (like this).

```
kubectl get --namespace default secret kubeapps-operator-token -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 -d
```